# How to handle setDelegate: when using multipe threads

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, multithreading

I've come across an issue with using a third party library, and am not sure what the common pattern to solve it is.

I'm using the asi-http-request class, which fetches http objects asynchronously using a thread.

In my objects dealloc() method, I do

```
[request setDelegate:nil];
[request release];
```

However the delegate is sometimes still called after this has happened. (I can see when this happens the delegate field of the request object is nil.) This sometimes causes a crash if the delegate has been destroyed already.

I believe this is a race condition. The code from ASIHTTPRequest that calls the delegate looks like this:

```
// Let the delegate know we are done
if ([self didFinishSelector] && [[self delegate] respondsToSelector:[self didFinishSelector]]) {
    [[self delegate] performSelectorOnMainThread:[self didFinishSelector] withObject:self waitUntilDone:[NSThread isMainThread]];
}
```

The problem happens if the performerSelectorOnMainThread has been called (but not completed) when the setDelegate call happens on the main thread.

One solution would be to add a wrapper around 'didFinishSelector' that checks (on the main thread) that the delegate is still non-nil before calling the selector, but this would result in a lot of wrappers.

There is some background here:

http://groups.google.com/group/asihttprequest/browse_thread/thread/721220b9645f4a42

All suggestions on the "normal" solution for this appreciated!

Thanks

Joseph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My original thoughts (wrapper around 'didFinishSelector' that checks on the main thread that the delegate is still non-nil before calling the selector) turned out to be the correct solution, as confirmed by helpful folks over on the apple dev forums:

https://devforums.apple.com/message/255935#255935

To avoid my worry of ending up with lots of wrappers, I managed to create only a single wrapper:

```
- (void)callSelectorCallback:(SEL *)selectorPtr withTarget:(id *)targetPtr
{
    id target = *targetPtr;
    SEL selector = *selectorPtr;

    if (!selector || !target)
        return;

    if ([target respondsToSelector:selector])
    {
        [target performSelector:selector withObject:self];
    }
}

- (void)callSelector:(SEL *)selector withDelegate:(id *)target
{
    if (!*selector || !*target)
        return;

    SEL callback = @selector(callSelectorCallback:withTarget:);
    NSMethodSignature *signature = [ASIHTTPRequest instanceMethodSignatureForSelector:callback];
    NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature:signature];
    [invocation setSelector:callback];
    [invocation setTarget:self];
    [invocation setArgument:&selector atIndex:2];
    [invocation setArgument:&target atIndex:3];

    [invocation performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(invoke) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:[NSThread isMainThread]];
}
```

then when I want to call the delegate, the code just looks something like this:

```
[self callSelector:&didFinishSelector withDelegate:&delegate];
```

As best I can tell from experiments & code analysis (and assuming setDelegate is only called from the main thread), this is 100% safe. It could be made safe for the non-main thread calls to setDelegate by taking the object lock inside callSelectorCallback.

Answer (score 1):

For dealing with objects across threads, you should almost always retain them.  Basically,

```
id delegate = [[self delegate] retain];
if ([self didFinishSelector] && [delegate respondsToSelector:[self didFinishSelector]]) {
    [delegate performSelectorOnMainThread:[self didFinishSelector]
                               withObject:self 
                            waitUntilDone:[NSThread isMainThread]];
}
[delegate release];
```

Technically, the delegate could be dealloc-ed in between [self delegate] and the subsequent retain, and I'm not at all sure if Apple's @synthesized atomic accessors protect against this or not, but I believe the only way to solve this is in the accessor,

```
[[delegate retain] autorelease];
```

best of luck, race conditions get the best of us!

Comment: Even amending a custom accessor in that way would not solve the problem, since the delegate could be deallocked before the -delegate method arrives at its `[delegate retain]` expression. You might try synthesizing the accessors (if changing the ASIHTTPRequest code is even an option—that is, if you don't mind contributing to it or are OK with forking it), but I think the only real solution is to rearrange things that your delegate never dies before the ASIHTTPRequest does.

Comment: Changing ASIHTTPRequest is certainly an option (and probably the preferred solution). I think Jared's [[delegate retain] autorelease] strategy (inside of ASIHTTPRequest's delegate accessor) does work, as the retain is happening inside the atomic accessor (ie. with a lock taken)?

Comment: It's also interesting to note that this approach still results in the delegate receiving messages after setDelegate:nil has been called. I guess that may be harmless, but it's unexpected.

Comment: JosephH: The accessor isn't atomic if you didn't `@synthesize` it or otherwise write it to be atomic. Even then, any code outside the accessor, including the code in the answer, is not subject to the accessors' declarations of atomicity (or lack of declarations of lack of atomicity). The only solution entirely within ASIHTTPRequest is to guard *all* code that uses the delegate, plus the entire body of `setDelegate:`, with a mutex lock. When you reach for a lock, you're probably doing it wrong; as I said, the real solution is to not kill off your delegate before your request in the first place.